# creating two button in the same layout side by side?

Tags: android

I want to make two buttons in the same layout side by side but I want also they stick together in that layout.. 
You can see what I mean in the link below

https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=4854788471&photo_id=9770651757

Comment: Use frame layout here.

Comment: "You cannot access that photo" - Use imgur or something.

Comment: explain more...

Comment: Your point is not clear, please explain more......

Answer (score 0):

Use linear layout with orientation horizontal

```
  <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button02" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Übernehmen">
        </Button>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button03" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:text="Abbrechen">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

i hope its works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i see your image.
Use LinearLayout with weight feature.
i have created same ayout as you required.
use textview instead button with selector.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:background="#e2e2e2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:text="YES" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7sp"
        android:background="@color/BLACK" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="NO" />
</LinearLayout>
```

selector file txt_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/color_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!--color_pressed= "#969696" -->
<item android:drawable="@color/txt_color" /> <!--txt_color= "#e2e2e2" -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope Below code will work for you.

for divider in button I used textview to stick two button as you shown in image.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="YES" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey_color" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="NO" />
</LinearLayout>
```